# Opening a program using ProcessStartInfo when program name contains a space c#

Tags: c#

The issue lies with the space between Test & Program. How do I get around this so Process.Start(Info); works as intended. I could change Test Program.exe to TestProgram.exe and this would work perfectly. Ive looked at similar questions but non seem to answer my question. Most mention String Replace or altering the string. I dont want to alter the string but regognise there is a space and process as normal.

Apoligies if this has been asked before but I cant seem to find it so please post the link if this has. Thanks

My code

```
 private string program_name = "Test Program.exe";

ProcessStartInfo Info = new ProcessStartInfo();
                Info.Arguments = "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 0 & start " + program_name;
                Info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                Info.CreateNoWindow = true;
                Info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                Process.Start(Info);
```

Comment: So why don’t you just add quotes around `program_name`?

Comment: `Info.Arguments = $"/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 0 & start \"{program_name}\"";`

Comment: Have you considered setting the "FileName" to program_name instead of "cmd.exe"?

Comment: @RufusL Thanks for the comment. This just opens a command prompt window with the current directory of the program name and doesnt open the actual program?

Comment: Don't run it via `cmd.exe`. Why do you feel the need to do that? Its a common approach - but 99.99% of the time it is wrong.

Comment: In that case it must be using the overload where the window title is the first argument. Try: `Info.Arguments = $"/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 0 & start \"\" \"{program_name}\""; `

Comment: What is the point of the `choice` command in that command line if you don't accept user input and don't do anything with the result?

Comment: I’m not really sure what you’re hoping to achieve with that “offer the user a single choice that accepts itself after zero seconds” but - if you want to delay launching the program by some seconds consider doing it in c# instead with an `await Task.Delay(x)` before you do `Process.Start(“test program.exe”)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific example - which seems a little odd, if you don't mind me saying - the program you are executing is part of the argument list and needs to be wrapped in double quotes like so:

```
Info.Arguments = "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 0 & start \"" + program_name + "\"";
```

Or, just in case `program_name` is already quoted:

```
var quoted_name = $"\"{program_name.Trim('"')}\"";
Info.Arguments = "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 0 & start " + quoted_name;
```

If that's really what you're using rather than a contrived example (which is perfectly fine as an example) then it would be simpler to just run the program directly rather than passing it as a commandline to `cmd.exe`, in which case you don't need the quotes at all:

```
ProcessStartInfo Info = new ProcessStartInfo();
Info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Info.CreateNoWindow = true;
Info.FileName = program_name; // or program_name.Trim('"')
Process.Start(Info);
```

Since you're hiding the console window anyway there doesn't seem much point explicitly invoking `cmd.exe` and having it wait around for the program to complete.

Comment: Thankyou. Calling the program directly did the trick.

Comment: @craig-burgess if this answer is the one you chose you should click the gray check mark to turn it green. This marks the question as answered on the dashboard. You should also upvote any answers that you found helpful, including the one you check

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Info.Arguments = "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 0 & start \"" + program_name + "\"";
```